# Sending 100's of page request at the same time

Tags: performance, request

I want to test the performance of my website. I have hosted it on godaddy and I want to see how it performance when 100s of users are trying to access it.

Is their a way to do the above? Is their a script that can be developed to send multiple page request?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Consider trying [Jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) or [siege](http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/).

Comment: @anita.kcx : If Jmeter setup is a bit too much you could try http://blazemeter.com/

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) is commonly used for doing load testing (which is pretty much what you are describing).  There are also a bunch of services that will do it for you (some free, most with varying costs).

You could simply script curl or whet to beat on it in parallel but just throwing load at it isn't terribly useful if you don't also track how the site performs under the load (which is where the other tools come in).

One thing to watch out for is if you test just the base page/application or if you use a real browser engine to test the full page (including images and static resources).